# Does Lestrade guess/know that Sherlock is alive in the BBC series?

Tags: sherlock

Does Greg Lestrade know/guess that Sherlock is alive?

In the Many Happy Returns trailer to Season 3, he grins at the headline "The Game is back on".

Comment: I meant the prequel to season 3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwntNANJCOE

Answer (score 2):

I see no evidence that Lestrade believes that Sherlock is alive, in fact, **throughout** the trailer he's quite adamant that Sherlock is dead and that any theories of him being alive are ridiculous.

Any grin would just have been at a rueful memory of things Sherlock might say.

Indeed, he **continues** to consider Sherlock as dead until *The Empty Hearse* episode or as he puts it when another possible escape from death scenario is put to him.

> "Bollocks".

Comment: This does fit with Lestrade's character. It's pretty much a given that the police dislike Sherlock (partly because he outshines them, partly because he never fails to tell them that he outshines them). However, Lestrade (as a person) really likes Sherlock, and suffers the indignation and intellectual insults as long as Sherlock is beneficial to actually helping prevent/solve crimes. To that end, it makes sense that Lestrade would snicker at Sherlock's mannerisms, even if just thinking about them posthumously.

Comment: Yes. Some reasons that led me to wonder:                                                                  1. He doesn't express surprise when Sherlock resurfaces from the shadows to catch him smoking, this scene is shown before it is revealed to the public that Sherlock is alive 2. His actions in the trailer can also be interpreted as not wanting Anderson to know the truth because it is not yet time to reveal it